# How do I configure the proxy settings so that Eclipse can download new plugins?

Tags: eclipse, proxy

I am working with Eclipse 3.7, on an Windows XP environment behind a web proxy.

I want to install the [Groovy plugin](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Eclipse+Plugin) on a *newly unzipped* Eclipse Indigo (*Eclipse Java EE Indigo M4*).
I added the [update site](http://dist.codehaus.org/groovy/distributions/greclipse/snapshot/e3.7/) to the `Available Software Site` list.

But Eclipse is not able to retrieve the information of this plugin, and thus the installation is not possible...

If I put `Native` configuration in `General > Network Connections`, which does not have the `Auth` option selected, I get the following error when I trying to reach the update site:

```
HTTP Proxy Authentication Required: http://dist.codehaus.org/groovy/distributions/greclipse/snapshot/e3.7/content.xml
HTTP Proxy Authentication Required: http://dist.codehaus.org/groovy/distributions/greclipse/snapshot/e3.7/content.xml
Proxy Authentication Required
```

So now, I select `manual`, I define all correct information for the three schemas (HTTP, HTTPS, SOCKS): proxy, port, Auth, User and password.
However, when I try to reach the update site, Eclipse is indicating that he is `Fetching children of Groovy Eclipse`, but keep this status at 0%...

What is strange is that even if I put a wrong password in the `General > Network Connections` configuration, I don't get any error message.

**My questions:**

- What is wrong in my configuration?
- Is there another way to define the proxy configuration?
- Is there a way to get more information, to know what Eclipse is trying to do (the `workspace/.metadata/.log` doesn't contain any useful information) ?

Another problem (minor however) is that the modifications of the proxy settings seem to be handled only after an Eclipse restart.

---

*ps1:* Using my browser, I can reach the update site, so it is not blocked by the proxy.

*ps2:* This problem is not related to this plugin, as Eclipse behaves the same way for other plugin.

*ps3:* Here is the content of the `workspace/.metadata/.log` when I start Eclipse and try to install the plugin (all these logs are written during the startup, none when Eclipse tries to access the update site)

```
!SESSION 2011-05-02 10:38:58.681 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20101208-1300
java.version=1.6.0_20
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=fr_FR
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2011-05-02 10:39:02.228
!MESSAGE System property http.proxyHost is not set but should be XXX.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2011-05-02 10:39:02.228
!MESSAGE System property http.proxyPort is not set but should be 8080.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2011-05-02 10:39:02.244
!MESSAGE System property https.proxyHost is not set but should be XXX.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2011-05-02 10:39:02.244
!MESSAGE System property https.proxyPort is not set but should be 8080.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2011-05-02 10:39:02.244
!MESSAGE System property socksProxyHost is not set but should be XXX.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2011-05-02 10:39:02.244
!MESSAGE System property socksProxyPort is not set but should be 8080.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2011-05-02 10:39:02.244
!MESSAGE System property https.proxyHost is not set but should be XXX.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2011-05-02 10:39:02.244
!MESSAGE System property https.proxyPort is not set but should be 8080.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2011-05-02 10:39:02.244
!MESSAGE System property socksProxyHost is not set but should be XXX.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2011-05-02 10:39:02.244
!MESSAGE System property socksProxyPort is not set but should be 8080.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2011-05-02 10:39:02.244
!MESSAGE System property socksProxyHost is not set but should be XXX.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2011-05-02 10:39:02.244
!MESSAGE System property socksProxyPort is not set but should be 8080.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2011-05-02 10:39:02.447
!MESSAGE NLS missing message: TaskJobFactory_Refreshing_repository_configuration in: org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.ui.messages
```

---

*Edit*

If I add the following lines in my `eclipse.ini` file ([because of that](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=281472#c7)), it works:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttp.proxyHost=XXX
-Dhttp.proxyUser=XXX
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=XXX
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1
```

But why? Does this problem still exists in Eclipse 3.7?

Comment: i have a similar question: how i install eclipse update from a proxy server (or cache) in ubuntu? or should i ask this in ubuntu server? thx

Comment: The issue exists even in Eclipse Neon (2017-05-12)! 6 years have gone by :O

Comment: @Ram .... and in Eclipse Oxygen (2017-09-21)!!

Answer (score 335, accepted):

I had the same problem. I installed Eclipse 3.7 into a new folder, and created a new workspace. I launch Eclipse with a -data argument to reference the new workspace.

When I attempt to connect to the marketplace to get the SVN and Maven plugins, I get the same issues described in OP.

After a few more tries, I **cleared the proxy settings for SOCKS** protocol, and I was able to connect to the marketplace.

So the solution for me was to configure the manual settings for HTTP and HTTPS proxy, clear the settings for SOCKS, and restart Eclipse.

Comment: Same here, I reported a bug and it was ignored.  The guy basically said it 'works for me'.  In the past 10 years, I have never had the proxy settings work as expected.  I have to find some hidden configuration setting.

Comment: Indeed, even though it looked like the SOCKS value was totally empty, this suddenly worked after (for MANUAL config) I highlighted the SOCKS row, clicked "Clear", then OK, then restarted eclipse.  If this isn't a bug, I don't know what is.

Comment: Thanks you so much. I would never have thought that this could be a solution. I was inside corporate firewall and trying to update a cleacase plugin was failing all the time. This seems to solve the problem.

Comment: I had this issue also, and tried the steps above.  But it still would not resolve.  I had to edit [eclipse install directory]/configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.core.net.prefs and reset proxyData/SOCKS/hasAuth=false. Then follow the steps in this answer

Comment: Thanks you! This only worked for me after rebooting my Ubuntu machine. No settings change I made would convince it otherwise.

Comment: You might also need to remove "proxy bypass" rules.

Answer (score 39):

Manual + disable SOCKS didn't work for me (still tried to use SOCKS and my company proxy refused it),
**Native** + changed **eclipse.ini** worked for me

```
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient
-Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttp.proxyUser=mydomain\myusername
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=mypassword
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1
```

These settings require IDE restart (sometimes with `-clean -refresh` command line options).
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=281472

---

**Java8, Eclipse Neon3, slow proxy server:**

```
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4
-Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxy>
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttps.proxyHost=<proxy>
-Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
-DsocksProxyHost=
-DsocksProxyPort=
-Dhttp.proxyUser=<user>
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=<pass>
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf.retry=5
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.connectTimeout=15000
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.readTimeout=1000
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.retryAttempts=20
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.closeTimeout=1000
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.connectTimeout=3000
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.readTimeout=1000
```

Comment: Hi, is the "Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors" part required?

Comment: What is the difference between `httpclient4` and `httpclient` ?

Comment: Confirmed for oxygen.2 and 3A.

Comment: It does work for Eclipse Oxygen, just use Native network settings and add those lines in eclipse.ini

Answer (score 16):

There is an eclipse.ini (sts.ini) parameter that can help:

```
-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true
```

A lot of effort wasted on this trivial setting each time I change the work environment... See one of the related bugs on [eclipse bugzilla](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/148701/).

Comment: Just in case it affects anyone else, using `useSystemProxies=true` with Eclipse Oxygen caused problems for me because it did not properly detect env variable `https_proxy`. So while http pages worked fine, https pages would not load. Also note that once you set this setting, the settings read from the environment override the Eclipse proxy settings.

Answer (score 14):

Just to add to the thread as a *POSSIBLE* solution, I faced a similar issue when developing on a Linux system that was behind a company firewall.  However, using a Windows XP machine, Eclipse was able to access different update sites just fine as both the manual and native network connection providers worked just fine using the company proxy.

After stumbling around for some time, I came across a discussion about using NTLMv2 and an implementation to be found at http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/.  To whomever posted this, I give much credit to as it helped me get past the issue running on Linux.  As a side note, I was using Eclipse 3.6.2 / Helios on both the Linux and Windows distros.

Best of luck on finding a solution!

Comment: I've tried all the other suggestions, but nothing helped. Installing CNTLM did the trick. I'm on Windows 7, JDK 1.7, Eclipse 4.3.2

Comment: @slu Glad to hear this worked for you! To date, this is still working for me, even with migrating to the latest versions of both the JDK and Eclipse.

Comment: Using cntlm as local proxy works for me as well. I had to disable socks, too, otherwise  localhost:port won't work with luna eclipse.

Answer (score 14):

finally work for me !

In Eclipse, Window > Preferences > General > Network Connections, 
set Active Provider to **Native**
add to **eclipse.ini** :

```
-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy
-Dhttp.proxyUser=mydomain\myusername
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=mypassword
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|192.168.*|10.*
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4
```

Answer (score 5):

I installed HandyCache, in them install link on my general proxy.

In IE set proxy 127.0.0.1.

In Eclipse, Window > Preferences > General > Network Connections, set Active Provider = Native.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I go to
\eclipse\configuration.settings\org.eclipse.core.net.prefs set the property systemProxiesEnabled to true manually and restart eclipse.