# Proxy problems with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm experiencing some weird problems on using web stuff in Eclipse (Indigo, Indigo SR2 and Juno). My proxy configurations seems to be messed when Eclipse tries to do sth on web.

My browsers stop to communicate and I have to restart my machine in order to restore my Internet access again (or close Eclipse and browser and force the browser to reload proxy configurations). In Eclipse, the communication is unstable, working/not working sometimes.

My "NetWork Connections" are set to Manual, where proxy address, port, auth, user and passord are set to HTTP and HTTPS schemas (I didn't use it for SOCKS due to update issues - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857499/how-do-i-have-to-configure-the-proxy-settings-so-eclipse-can-download-new-plugin)).

I have no idea of what is happening and why, and how to fix it. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

It is very unlikely that Eclipse influences your global settings. If anything outside of Eclipse does not work, should look there for the problem first. Eclipse can either use your system wide settings, or it's own overrides.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your frustration - hard to know what is going wrong.. I really don't see what Eclipse can be doing to cause this though. I can suggest some further troubleshooting steps though.

1. Can you test the proxy config on any other machine?
2. Can you browse normally on this machine at other times?
3. Can you go to the same URL in browser that Eclipse is going to?
4. Perhaps do you have Eclipse checking all sites for updates (Help > Software) and this is just network slowdown?
5. When you are experiencing this effect, can you ping outside sites?