# Username issue with Titanium Studio

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I am using the Titanium Studio version 3.1.1 GA

When I create a new project, while creating it shows **Unable to create new project. [ERROR] Missing required option "--username"** alert and after that I am unable to create the project in it.

I am logged into Titanium with valid username/password. I set the proxy and port according to my office setup.

I searched it, but not getting the satisfactory answer which can solve it.

Though it is the same as Eclipse, and using the same services, I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857499/how-do-i-have-to-configure-the-proxy-settings-so-eclipse-can-download-new-plugin) too. But I am getting the same error

Below is my log file entry:

```
!SESSION 2013-07-02 12:45:22.411 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=3.1.1.201306112235
java.version=1.6.0_24
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2013-07-02 12:45:31.640
!MESSAGE System property http.proxyHost is not set but should be XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2013-07-02 12:45:31.647
!MESSAGE System property http.proxyPort is not set but should be 8085.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2013-07-02 12:45:31.649
!MESSAGE System property https.proxyHost is not set but should be XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2013-07-02 12:45:31.650
!MESSAGE System property https.proxyPort is not set but should be 8085.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2013-07-02 12:45:31.651
!MESSAGE System property socksProxyHost is not set but should be XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2013-07-02 12:45:31.654
!MESSAGE System property socksProxyPort is not set but should be 8085.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2013-07-02 12:45:31.658
!MESSAGE System property https.proxyHost is not set but should be XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2013-07-02 12:45:31.659
!MESSAGE System property https.proxyPort is not set but should be 8085.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2013-07-02 12:45:31.660
!MESSAGE System property socksProxyHost is not set but should be XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2013-07-02 12:45:31.661
!MESSAGE System property socksProxyPort is not set but should be 8085.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2013-07-02 12:45:31.662
!MESSAGE System property socksProxyHost is not set but should be XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2013-07-02 12:45:31.663
!MESSAGE System property socksProxyPort is not set but should be 8085.

!ENTRY com.appcelerator.titanium.acs.ui 4 0 2013-07-02 12:45:44.487
!MESSAGE (Build 3.1.1.201306112235) [ERROR]  Failed to log into Node.ACS:
```

Please have a look if someone has faced the same problem and solved it or someone has the solution for it. I need it solved asap.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

open the node.js console and type 
titanium login
use your titanium user/pass and then press enter
That's worked for me.

Comment: I was using Titanium behind a proxy so that error was coming. It doesn't work behind proxy.