# Unable to connect Sonar Eclipse Plugin to Sonar Server

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

I have installed the latest version on the Sonar Eclipse Plugin on an Eclipse Juno 3.8. I am desperatly trying to connect the plugin to our running instance of Sonar. I'm behind a NTLM v2 Proxy. Hereunder, details of my configuration and  my attempts.

Versions of products :

- Eclipse 3.8,
- Sonar Eclipse Plugin (Java Analyzer & m2e Connector) 3.2.0.20130627-1142-RELEASE,
- SonarQube Server 3.7 (running on `http://source01:9000`, in the LAN, not behind the proxy, direct connection possible).

Trying to access with the following proxy configurations with an without http_proxy variable in the configuration:

- direct with http_proxy : failure,
- direct without http_proxy : success (but unable to use other Eclipse feature accessing Internet like the Marketplace),
- native (with or without http_proxy) : failure,
- manual (with or without http_proxy): failure.

I systematically got org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException in the logs (trying to access `http://source01:9000/api/authentication/validate` which work in a browser).

No more idea on what to test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have finally found the problem seeking for a different one (Tomcat WST server started but Eclipse was unable to connect to it and timed out).

The problem comes from a strange and unpredictable behavior of the SOCKS proxy parameter.

When SOCKS proxy is defined, in some undefined cases, both starting a WST server or connecting to a SonarQube server through the plugin fail, whereas other functions like plugin installs work like a charm.

The solution came from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6459816/256561 and is to clear SOCKS proxy settings.