# Connection timeout when getting plugin list or updating Eclipse PDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pdt

I'm working on win 7 and trying to get Zend Eclipse to run properly for a CakePHP project. But when try to access the plugin list via the welcome page I get this error:

> A problem occurred while accessing the update site.
>   RemoteBundleDiscoveryStrategy failed with an error
>   Unable to read repository at http://downloads.zend.com/studio-eclipse/updates-extra/10_0/pdt_directory.xml.
>   Connect timed out

I've tried severalt solutions I found on the net but nothing worked. My proxy settings are fine since I can access all sites via the internal browser of eclipse. My guess is, that there is some restriction in the Windows administration that is keeping me from getting the plugin list.

When I try to update Eclipse the update window tries half an hour to contact the software site and after that I get this error message:

> Some sites could not be found.  See the error log for more detail.
>   Communication with repository at http://downloads.zend.com/studio-eclipse/updates/10_0 failed.
>   Connect timed out

Comment: I've answered a similar question, try these things: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7722815/207764

Comment: Yeah I already tried every answer given there. My guess is that there is some functionality that is blocked by the administration.

Comment: It's possible. If you can, check the logs of the firewall. It's possible the Eclipse executable is blocked from accessing the network.

Comment: If Eclipse would be blocked, wouldn't the internal browser be blocked too?

Comment: If it was blocked on program level, yes. It could also be restriction on type of traffic or the port it communicates on. You will need to talk with your support or network admins. If outside traffic isn't allowed, they will need to create an internal update site that contains all the plugins you will require.

Comment: Is there a way to find out what exactly needs to be opened, so I can tell my admin exactly what to do? I'm not very familiar with administration and I'm sure my admin has lots of stuff to do beside my problems.

Comment: Think its 80 and 443. You could set up Eclipse to use a different port, such as 8080. Also see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857499/how-do-i-have-to-configure-the-proxy-settings-so-eclipse-can-download-new-plugin

Comment: I already changed to ports for all connection types. But still won't work.

Comment: I was just put into a group with (as far as I know) all rights, but there is still the connection timeout when trying to get the plugin list....

Comment: Netbeans on the other hand is working fine. I can download updates and install plugins....

Comment: Could it be that Eclipse isn't saving my Login and Password for the Proxy Server? I have to input it every time I restart Eclipse. And the username isn't shown in the Proxy entries after I just changed them in the "Edit Proxy Entry" form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally!!**

The problem was that is were actually two problems. First one was that Eclipse wasn't saving the username and password for the proxy settings. After finally finding the eclipse error log in

> "{eclipse-workspace}/.metadata/.log"

(there seems to be no way to view the file in zend-eclipse itself) I found out that Eclipse was trying to save the password-file into the Administrator's user directory but had no access. (Oh what a surprise)

Putting this into the "zend-eclipse-php.ini" worked for me:

> -eclipse.keyring  C:\eclipse\keyring.txt

After this was done I could finally save username and password for the proxy but still no connection. When I took another look into the error log I found this error:

> "!MESSAGE System property http.proxyHost is not set but should be {proxyname}
>   !MESSAGE System property http.proxyPort is not set but should be {proxyport}"

and 4 more for https and socks. After googling this error I came upon a fixed bug:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=281472
where it states that maybe the proxy refuses SOCKS. So I cleared the settings for SOCKS and tried again and IT WORKED! Finally!

Hope this description can anyone else with these problems.