# Not able to associate a project using Eclipse sonar plugin

Tags: sonarqube

I am using sonarcube 3.7.3 
I am using STS with below details:

Version: 3.6.3.SR1 
Build Id: 201501121239 
Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.1)

I have installed sonarcude eclipse plugin(SonarCubeJava Analyser 3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE) and when I try to associate my project with sonar using "Associate with SonarCude" option in STS then I am getting below error:

**One of your SonarQube server cannot be reached. Please check your connection settings.**

I am ot able to attach image as I am new user on this forum.

Can you suggest what could be the issue and possible solution. 
Let me know if there are any queries.

**The workspace log shows below:** 
!ENTRY org.sonar.ide.eclipse.ui 4 0 2015-06-26 15:37:38.821
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:423)
org.sonar.ide.eclipse.ui.internal.command.ConfigureProjectsCommand$1.run(Configu    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
Caused by: org.sonar.ide.eclipse.wsclient.ConnectionException: Query:  at Root exception:
org.sonar.ide.eclipse.wsclient.ConnectionException: Query: http://sonarserver/api/resources?scopes=PRJ&qualifiers=TRK,BRC&verbose=false&
g.sonar.ide.eclipse.wsclient.internal.SonarWSClientFacade.findAll(SonarWSClientFacade.java:109) org.sonar.ide.eclipse.wsclient.internal.SonarWSClientFacade.listAllRemoteModules(SonarWSClientFacade.java:89)

The url in above log is working fine when I check it in browser.

Comment: Are you able to reach the sonar server from your browser?

Comment: Yes, I am able to reach our sonar server. If I paste the url "http://sonarserver/api/resources?scopes=PRJ&qualifiers=TRK,BRC&verbose=false&" listed in logs then it gives me results in browser.                                                           Also in STS IDE, I set-up my sonar server and test connection give "successful"

Comment: I relooked at the eclipse workspace logs and looking more closely, i can see a final error as "read timed out". Could this be the issue. Am i reading the log correctly. If yes, then what could be possible solution. I am sharing the logs as below:java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: org.sonar.ide.eclipse.wsclient.ConnectionException: Query: http://sonarserverurl
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
Root exception:
org.sonar.ide.eclipse.wsclient.ConnectionException: Query: http://sonarserverurl
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing sonar from an enterprise network, you may be behind a proxy server. If so, please try proxy settings in eclipse under **General > Network Connections**

Checkout the below links:

[How do I have to configure the proxy settings so Eclipse can download new plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857499/how-do-i-have-to-configure-the-proxy-settings-so-eclipse-can-download-new-plugin)

http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-net-preferences.htm

Comment: Thanks. I missed mentioning it in my original post. I have already setup proxy connection and I could download sonar eclipse plugin only after setting up the proxy connection. I have setup the connection as "Manual" and specified details for HTTP and HTTPS. Intially I set-up SOCKS also but it was giving error so I ommited it.

Comment: Pankaj,
Did you try using older versions of sonar eclipse plugin, can you try v3.2?

Comment: I have tried to use older version of eclipse also but they are not working (I have checked 3.3.0, 3.2.0). I am facing this issue since the system have been upgraded to windows 7. Same sonar eclipse plugin was working fine on windowsXP(my previous configuration.                             Please suggest how I can resolve it as it has become a big issue.

Comment: Few questions:
Are you able to access sonar link in eclipse web browser?
Did you try installing older version of Eclipse or sonar plugin for eclipse?
Also, if proxy is configured with a pac file for the system please try using native rather than manually configuring it in eclipse.

Comment: Answers as below:   1) Yes I am able to access the sonar url when I paste same in the browser 2) yes I have tried Kepler also.Also additional information: I installed older version of sonar eclipse plugin also but same error in log 3) I have configured proxy using manual and it works fine. As I am able to install sonar eclipse plugin after setting the proxy manually.  Additional information: The sonar eclipse plugin (3.2.0) was working fine with Eclipse kepler on a Windows XP system.The issue is present since my system has changed to windows7. Please help.

Comment: I relooked at the eclipse workspace logs and looking more closely, i can see a final error as "read timed out". Could this be the issue. Am i reading the log correctly. If yes, then what could be possible solution. I am sharing the logs as below:java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Caused by: org.sonar.ide.eclipse.wsclient.ConnectionException: Query: sonarserverurl Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out Root exception: org.sonar.ide.eclipse.wsclient.ConnectionException: Query: sonarserverurl Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Comment: You can try adding preview analysis property `sonar.preview.readTimeout` under Preferences>SonarQube>Preview Analysis Properties.
Set the value to a high value, say 600 may be 3000 :)

Comment: I noticed one more thing. When I try to associate a project  in eclipse with sonar then I see a memory  issue in server logs. I also noticed that my sonar server has numerous projects(400+) configured. Can this be the cause the issue and can removing some projects may resolve it. let me know if somebody has experienced this on their projects.                             The sonar serverlogs show:2015.07.21 10:53:59 ERROR rails
Java::JavaLang::OutOfMemoryError (Java heap space):
  org.jruby.util.ByteList.<init>(ByteList.java:91)
  org.jruby.RubyArray.join(RubyArray.java:1745)

Comment: Oh.I thought issue was during analysis. 
Out of Memory issue could be due to a project analysis happening somewhere else. I don't see any reason for out of memory on server when associating a project.
Btw can you try setting up the same version of sonar on local, run an analysis and try associating it to the local server?