# Spring boot Project generation issue

Tags: java, spring

I am Creating new project in spring boot with spring boot starter project but that shows me SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

[image]

Comment: What Java version do you use?

Comment: i am using java1.8

Comment: Can you use the browser and access the URL start.spring.io

Comment: yes i can use use but then this error comes in pom see:-Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.2.2.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM

Comment: Do you have direct internet access or are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Behind a proxy!

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857499/how-do-i-have-to-configure-the-proxy-settings-so-eclipse-can-download-new-plugin

Answer (score 0):

**Hey can you try this**

Change the service URL https to http

> Service URL  http://start.spring.io

Comment: Not Working For Me

Answer (score 0):

Try with http://start.spring.io/ It should work then.

Answer (score -1):

The problem appears when your server has a self-signed certificate. To work around it you can add the certificate to the list of trusted certificates of your JVM.

check this article on how to do this https://better-coding.com/how-to-add-ssl-certificate-into-java-cacerts-file-and-jks-keystore/

Comment: The service URL is the official Spring URL

Comment: Yes but even so, he should add  "the official Spring URL" to his cacert

Comment: add the certificate also but still same issue  check this :    keytool -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_231\lib\security\cacerts" -import -alias https://start.spring.io/  -file C:\Desktop\springio.cer is it correct!