# how to configue a dbeaver proxy connection to a private maven repository

Tags: java, oracle, maven, dbeaver

I am using an internal maven/artifactory repository on my network.

I am trying to intialize an Oracle Connection with DBeaver 7.1.0. (not the eclipse plugin, the standalone program)

Each time it initializes, it fails to download the drivers.
with the error

```
Error Resolving Dependencies
  Maven artifact 'maven:/com.oracle.database.xml:xmlparserv2:RELEASE' not found
```

I'm assuming this is because the proxy is blocking outside access to download files.

Knowing the contents of my ~/.m2/settings.xml

```
       <proxies>
         <proxy>
           <host>myproxy.foo</host>
           <port>80</port>
         </proxy>
       <proxies>
       <profiles>
        <profile>
          ...
          <repositories>
            <repository>
              <id>foobar</id>
              <name>mystuff</id>
              <url>https://my-interal-maven.foo/artifactory/mystuff</url>
```

what are the steps to configure the connection correctly so it can download the files?

**EDIT**: I bypassed using maven and manually copied the JARs into the settings, like the answer given by @FeodorG

[image]

Basically, when trying to get the driver working it would break when
in Driver Settings -> "Download" throws error resolving dependencies...
Error resolving dependencies
Maven artifact 'maven:/com.oracle.database.nls:orai18n:RELEASE' not found

so I would go grab that jar in mvnRepository:
and repeat for each other entry that would fail at downloading

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.nls/orai18n/12.2.0.1
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.xml/xmlparserv2/12.2.0.1
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.xml/xdb6/12.2.0.1
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.nls/orai18n/12.2.0.1
```

After replacing all entries with JARs on my filesystem... the connection worked!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I configure the proxy settings so that Eclipse can download new plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857499/how-do-i-configure-the-proxy-settings-so-that-eclipse-can-download-new-plugins)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I had the same issue (all kinds of security settings issues on corporate networks were preventing me from setting up the driver).
My workaround was to get the Oracle driver jar files on my local drive somehow, then I defined my own Oracle driver by going to Database --> Driver manager in DBeaver.
From there I defined a new driver, by adding a file as a pointer to the Oracle jar file driver on my local drive, and then I clicked Find Class.
It found the class and then I just filled in some details for the default port etc.
Then I creted a new connection with the driver I had just created, entered username and password and it worked.
So, in short, I just brought the jar files to my local drive and created a new driver and a new connection.

Comment: Thanks, a good workaround, I posted a walkthrough in my Edited question

Answer (score 3):

In my case I have a proxy and a private repository and what works for me was to define the private repository URL as a new data source in Windows->Preferences->Connections->Drivers->maven and the click on Add.

Answer (score 1):

This time I am using Windows 10 and I am behind a proxy.
Actually the problem was not to configure it(for proxy downloads) nor the Maven repository URL (that could be misspelled).

The problem was the folder permissions that could not accept the driver to be saved in the `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\drivers\maven\maven-central` folder.

I just grant full permission to Everyone on the DBeaverData folder recursively but it is not the most secure setup. You can change "Everyone" to just your user instead. It worked.

```
takeown /f %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\* /r
    
icacls %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData /grant Everyone:F /t
```